# In jQuery, Is it possible to store a wildcard for further use in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

For example, if I have 4 buttons and divs such as these:

```
<button class="country-denmark"></button>
<button class="country-denmark"></button>
<button class="country-germany"></button>
<button class="country-norway"></button>

<div class="country-denmark"></div>
<div class="country-denmark"></div>
<div class="country-germany"></div>
<div class="country-norway"></div>
```

In jQuery, I have an on-click function with a wildcard selector, like this:

```
$("button[class^='country-']").on('click', function() {
  // Add class to divs that match the wildcard of this
  $("div[class^='country-']").addClass( className );
});
```

If I clicked on the button with the class `country-germany`, how could I store just the "germany" part and then find the div(s) that match that same wildcard?

Comment: Use `data-` rather than classes, then just match the two.  `$("button.country").on("click", function() { var country = $(this).data("country"); $("div[data-country=" + country + "]").addClass(...); })` with `<button class="country" data-country="denmark">..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

But I'd also update the elements a little to make it a little more straightforward to get the intended-value:

```
<button class="country-denmark" data-for="denmark"></button>
<button class="country-denmark" data-for="denmark"></button>
<button class="country-germany" data-for="germany"></button>
<button class="country-norway" data-for="norway"></button>

<div class="country-denmark" data-country="denmark"></div>
<div class="country-denmark" data-country="denmark"></div>
<div class="country-germany" data-country="germany"></div>
<div class="country-norway" data-country="norway"></div>
```

From here you just set the item in sessionStorage:

```
$("button[class^='country-']").on('click', function() {
    let country = $(this).data("for");

    let selectedCountry;

    $("div").each(function() {
        if ($(this).data("country") == country) {
            selectedCountry = $(this).data("country");
        }
    });

    sessionStorage.setItem("selectedCountry", selectedCountry);
});
```

To read the value later, use `sessionStorage.getItem()`

```
var selectedCountry = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedCountry");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is been quite a while since I touched jQuery, but if I remember correctly you can use jQuery-`this` for that.

```js
$("button[class^='country-']").on('click', function() {
  // Add class to divs that match the wildcard of this
  const className = $(this).attr('class')
  $(`div.${className}`).addClass( className );
});
```